# Not able to create repository

Tags: git, cygwin

I installed GIT and Cygwin GIT client. When command window opens, and $ prompt appears, I type in:

Git Init

It says:

Baash: Command not found.

Comment: Are you sure 'Baash' isn't a typo in this question?

Answer (score 4):

Be careful with uppercase. You should type it all lowercase :

```
git init
```

If it still doesn't work type this command:

```
echo $PATH
```

Then look for the git binary in the directories listed by this command. If you can't find it reinstall git in one of those directories or add your git binary's directory to this list (google "add a directory to my path").

Comment: If 'Baash' is a typo, then this is what makes the most sense.

Answer (score 2):

"Baash" ? Do you have a script which has #!/bin/baash at the top of it, instead of #!/bin/bash?

Comment: I don't know. But when I installed Cygwin client on Windows, this is what is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Was it not rather:

```
bash: $: command not found
```

Which would indicate that git is not referenced in the `PATH` environment variable?
Or that you try typing:

```
$ git init
```

instead of

```
git init
```

(do not type the `$`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
type git
```

It should respond with:

```
git is /usr/bin/git
```

Try:

```
/usr/bin/git init
```

Which should respond with:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
```

Also try:

```
echo $SHELL
```

Which should return:

```
/bin/bash
```

You can also try:

```
file /usr/bin/git
```

Which should give you:

```
/usr/bin/git: MS-DOS executable PE  for MS Windows (console) Intel 80386 32-bit
```